# Extract certain bytes from iscsi packets programmatically

Tags: wireshark, pcap, libpcap, iscsi

I have a ton of wireshark traces containing varying amount of ISCSI packets. I need to parse out the command being sent by the initiator (in bytes) and write it to a file for each packet. I was originally going to do this manually, as it is easily viewable inside the wireshark application (see SS below), but some of these traces are huge (1-2 Gb), and it would take forever to do by hand.

I've been looking into tshark and rawshark documentation, but I'm not sure either is able to get me what I need. A friend suggested using libpcap to parse the traces myself, but from what I can tell I'd need to find some way to identify the bytes I need to pull out of each packet. Ideally I'd like to use something that recognizes it for me (ie wireshark's ISCSI dissector).

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I need some way to parse out these commands from each ISCSI packet without looking through the raw packet data and trying to identify which bytes I need. As a note - It's not always the last 16 bytes in the packet as shown above, so I can't just go through and take the last 16 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

If you export the packets to PDML/XML (File->Export...->File->Save As Type PDML) you will get a nice XML file with all the protocol fields. You may be able to use this for your requirements, or use it as an index to locate the raw bytes in each packet.

[image: screen cap of PDML iscsi packet]